# Flex : Draw ellipse on Image?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an [`Image`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html) object and I wish to draw an ellipse on it.

I have tried with:

```
imageObj.graphics.beginFill( 0x0000FF, 0.5 );
imageObj.graphics.drawEllipse( position.x, position.y, 10, 10 );
imageObj.graphics.endFill();
```

However, it doesn't draw anything at all.

How can I draw a graphic primitive on an `Image` object?

Comment: similar to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014836/drawing-over-an-loaded-image-with-mouse/5023660#5023660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot draw elipse directly on a image, you need to draw on a UIComponent.

The following link may help you:

http://groups.google.com/group/macromedia.flex.flex_builder/browse_thread/thread/bbcfc4e3e0a2e133

http://www.axelscript.com/2008/06/11/drawing-in-flex-using-the-uicomponent/